# how to run apcupsd on Debian testing having systemd instead of sysv

Tags: debian, usb, ups

There is a Debian [wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/apcupsd#Configuring_.28Single_UPS_Device.29) which tells what needs to be configured in order for apcupsd to run nicely. But as the page says in the first para itself, it runs or works only on sysv and now everything is systemd in Debian. Can anybody tell me what configuration should I do and what steps I need to do to get the same output in systemd which was in sysv. FWIW it's this [one](https://www.apc.com/shop/in/en/products/APC-Power-Saving-Back-UPS-Pro-1000-with-LCD-230V-India/P-BR1000G-IN)

I was able to get some detailed info. on the USB via lsusb :-

```
$ sudo lsusb -v -d 051d:0002
[sudo] password for shirish: 

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x051d American Power Conversion
  idProduct          0x0002 Uninterruptible Power Supply
  bcdDevice            0.90
  iManufacturer           1 American Power Conversion
  iProduct                2 Back-UPS RS 1000G-IN FW:900.L8 .I USB FW:L8
```

It does give more info. but don't think that's necessary here. If there is any info. needed please let me know.

I did configure the things as mentioned but still get in

```
$ cat /var/log/apcupsd.events | tail -1
2019-08-31 21:58:53 +0530  Communications with UPS lost.
```

I get the following in systemctl -

```
Sep 02 14:53:24 debian systemd[1]: Starting UPS power management daemon...
Sep 02 14:53:24 debian apcupsd[774]: apcupsd FATAL ERROR in apcconfig.c at line 672
Sep 02 14:53:24 debian apcupsd[774]: Terminating due to configuration file errors.
Sep 02 14:53:24 debian systemd[1]: apcupsd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 02 14:53:24 debian apcupsd[774]: apcupsd FATAL ERROR in apcconfig.c at line 672
```

I do see this on my mate display

[image: picture of apc ups in mate-power-manager]

Also

[image: backups-pro]

```
$ sudo apcupsd --version
[sudo] password for shirish: 
apcupsd 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian

$ apt-cache policy apcupsd
apcupsd:
  Installed: 3.14.14-3
  Candidate: 3.14.14-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.14.14-3 900
        900 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

That is the latest in Debian

https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apcupsd

Also upstream http://www.apcupsd.org/ seems to be kinda dead.

Comment: At first sight only the multi-ups init script is SysV specific on the wiki, so your problems probably lies with your apcupsd configuration. Run it in the foreground from a terminal (`-b`) and with some debugging enabled (`-d X`). If those work fine, share the output of `systemctl status apcupsd`.

Comment: could you elaborate as to what command you want me to run. I have shared the output as seen above.

Comment: I meant `apcupsd -b`, then `apcupsd -b -d 1` and similar with increasing debug levels, until it provides the necessary information. But the logs above already make clear that the configuration file is erroneous, so you'll clearly have to fix that. Unfortunately the error message is rather poor; I don't know whether higher debug levels will provide more details, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried but got the same error again and again, no more info. See http://paste.debian.net/1098518/

Comment: Please mention the version number of your apcupsd package.

Comment: added the asked info.